# Getting the ID of header image, even when set to random

Tags: theme-options, header-image

I was looking for a solution to reliably get the ID of the header image, either the user had choose a single or a random image.

The only way i've found to do this relies on accessing a Wordpress's private function:

```
    // HEADER IMAGE
    if ( is_random_header_image() ) {
        $header_data = _get_random_header_data();
    } else {
        $header_data = get_theme_mod('header_image_data');
    }
    $header_id   = isset( $header_data->attachment_id ) ? $header_data->attachment_id : false;
    $header_img  = $header_id ? new TimberImage( $header_id ) : null;
    $context['headerImage'] = $header_img ? $header_img : null;
```

Is this ok or considered to be a bad practice?